# Подскажите движки для создания 2D игр на C++

Tags: android

Начал изучение языка С++ для создания игр. Создавать движок с нуля без опыта вообще не стоит, по этому начал искать готовые. Спустя часа поиска по сайтам,  в голове всё перемешалось. В большинстве случаем рекомендуют конструкторы, которые мне не нужны. Юнити и Анриал тоже не рассматриваю, ибо в анриале проблемы с оптимизацией, а в юнити с графикой. Буду благодарен если подскажите движки для 2д игр, ибо как описал ранее, после всех статей и форумов в голове каламбур.

Comment: Именно C++? Cocos2d-x https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x

Comment: Да, выбрал С++, ибо пишут про него больше всего. Или же следует выбрать Java?

Comment: На Java есть классный движок https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx Я с ним работал, пока на Unity3d не перешёл.

Comment: А на Юнити больше преимуществ? Может все таки стоит перейти на него? Просто я смотрел ролики, говорят что для 2д игр он не очень.

Comment: В последней версии много инструментов именно для 2d добавили. Очень удобно и быстро теперь разрабатывать.